# angular js custom directive scope.$watch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I have made a custom directive bind to the `transform` attribute of my `svg` group :

## Custom Directive

```
app.directive('ngScale', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngScale, function (value) {
            element.attr('transform', "scale(" + value + ")");
        }, true);
    };
});
```

## SVG Group

```
<g ng-scale="{{vm.scale}}">...</g>
```

## Controller

```
vm.doStuff = function () {
    ...
    vm.scale *= 1.1;
}
```

## DOM after call to doStuff

```
<g ng-scale="1.1" transform="scale(1)">...</g>
```

The call to `doStuff` changes the scale value, and I can see the `ng-scale` attribute change in the DOM however the actual `transform` attribute only is populated on first run, and never updated again. Why is it so?

Comment: Why not just use the [ng-attr prefix](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)?

Answer (score 0):

To get the watcher to work, don't use interpolation (double curly brackets) when using the directive.

### SVG Group

```
<g xd-scale="vm.scale">...</g>
```

### The directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('xdScale', function () {
    return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.xdScale, function (value) {
            console.log("Watch fired ", value);
            elem.attr('transform', "scale(" + value + ")");
        });
    };
});
```

The argument `attrs.xdScale` is a string. When the first argument to `$watch` is a string, the watch function is evaluated as an AngularJS expression. Double curly brackets don't work in an Angular expressions.

Also please don't use `ng-scale` as the name of the directive. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for AngularJS built-in directives.

To see the directive working, visit the [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a11k09L/).